# Consulta sobre socket.io y pub sub redis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs, socket.io, redis

Estoy haciendo un bot usando socket.io y pub sub con redis(se que no es necesario pero lo estoy usando para otras cosas tambien) ,el problema esta en que me bota datos repetidos .

[image: Chat repetido]

Este es el script que controla el envio de datos

**chat.js**

```
 $scope.sendMensaje=function(){
        $scope.mensaje=getMessageText();
        sendMessage($scope.mensaje);
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"/chat",
            data:{data:$scope.mensaje},
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(function(response,headers,config){

            console.log("Exito",headers,config);

        })
        .catch(function(response){
            console.log("Error",response);
        })

    };
```

Y aqui donde recibe

**chat.js**

```
var socket=io.connect("http://localhost:9001");

socket.on("new message",function(data){
    console.log("Mensaje recibido",data)
    setTimeout(function(){
                sendMessage(JSON.parse(data).data);

    },1000);
});
```

//sendMessage lo que hace es imprimir el mensaje en el chat

Del lado del servidor
**endpoint /chat**

```
app.post("/chat",(req,res)=>{
  console.log("Data de input",req.fields.data);

conversation.message(
{
  input: { text:req.fields.data }
},processResponse);
//redisClient.publish("chat",JSON.stringify(req.fields));
});
```

**processResponse.js**

```
var redisClient=require("../redisClient");

module.exports=function processResponse(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Que error era",err)
    //console.error(err); // something went wrong
  }
  else{
      console.log(response);

  // Display the output from dialog, if any.
  if (response.output.text.length != 0) {
    //console.log("Recibe de watson",response.output.text[0]);
    redisClient.publish("chat",JSON.stringify({data:response.output.text[0]}));
  }
  }
}
```

Ahora estoy haciendo unas pruebas,y he puesto un middleware que al cargar una pagina bajo cualquier endpoint /user , envia publica un contenido ,con publish.

**middlewareInitConversation**

```
var ConversationV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/conversation/v1');

var watsonConfig=require("../config/watson.conversation");

var conversation = new ConversationV1(watsonConfig);




module.exports=function(req,res,next){
console.log("MiddlewareInitConversation")

var processResponse=require("../auxiliares/processResponse");
conversation.message({}, processResponse);
 next();

}
```

**route user.js**

```
var express=require("express");
var router=express.Router();
var user=require("../models/user")
//////////
//////////
router.use(middlewareInitConversation);
////
router.route("/login").get(logged.unlogged,cUser.login_get).post(logged.unlogged,cUser.login_post);
////
```

**realtime.js**

```
module.exports=(server,sessionMiddleware)=>{
    var io=require("socket.io")(server);
    var redis=require("redis");
    var client=redis.createClient();

    client.subscribe("chat");

    io.use((socket,next)=>{
        sessionMiddleware(socket.request,socket.request.res,next);
        console.log("Esto esta aca",socket.request);
    });

    client.on("message",(channel,mensaje)=>{
        if(channel=="chat"){
            console.log("Mensaje recibido en realtime")
            io.emit("new message",mensaje);
        }

    });

    io.sockets.on("connection",(socket)=>{

        //console.log("Session de socket en middleware",socket);
    });
}
```

Entonces la logica es la siguiente , cuando entro a cualquier endpoint bajo /user ,se hace una consulta a la api de watson , para retornar el mensaje de inicio , luego se envia por publish a lo definido en realtime , se envia el dato bajo el canal chat , y en el cliente se recibe y muestra el mensaje.

Pero veo que se repite como ven en la imagen,

Estimo que es por estas lineas,que son las relacionadas al socket apenas carga la página , ahí claramente se ve 2 consultas al mismo ID , quizás por eso me arroja 2 veces el mismo resultado?,pero lo que no entiendo de donde salen esas 2 consultas?

```
http://localhost:9001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcdMtby XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:9001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcdMtby".
http://localhost:9001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcdMtcX&sid=no5jigx9xnRMqMvdAAAC XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:9001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcdMtcX&sid=no5jigx9xnRMqMvdAAAC".
http://localhost:9001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcdMtgP&sid=no5jigx9xnRMqMvdAAAC XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:9001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcdMtgP&sid=no5jigx9xnRMqMvdAAAC".
```